Firebase Auth may not be able to authenticate if you're using the signInWithRedirect
I try to solve from the above mentioned signInWithRedirect.
I do not understand, where should I whitelist the .../__/auth/handler custom redirect uri.
I try to follow the steps from here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/redirect-best-practices#update-authdomain
I would go for Option 1: Update your Firebase config to use your custom domain as your authDomain
[![image.png][1]][1]
I updated this:
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "<api-key>",
  authDomain: "<the-domain-that-serves-your-app>",
  databaseURL: "<database-url>",
  projectId: "<project-id>",
  appId: "<app-id>"
};

I searched for it again, and found this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#customizing-the-redirect-domain-for-google-sign-in
But I still do not understand where should I put the custom redirect uri with the ending ".../__/auth/handler".
Any answer would be appreciated.
